# Bugsense (Splunk > Mint) integration

Tags: ios, ios8

When I integrate the Bugsense into my project (iOS8), the `NSURLConnection` doesn't work properly. It returns *nil* when initialized.

**Example:**

```
NSURLConnection *tmp = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:... delegate:self];
```

The **tmp** is *nil*.

Does anybody know why that happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not to nil If you change the method of initialization.

> NSURLConnection *tmp = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
>   initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];